# jQuery scrollTop animate does not work on Chrome 34

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am using [jQuery.scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) in order to reach a certain DOM element w/ an easing effect. The plugin always worked like a charm in every browser.

Yesterday I noticed it didn't work on Chrome 34, and as I inspected the plugin I found it uses `$.animate`, so I reduced the problem to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp37m/3/):

```
$('body').animate({'scrollTop': 300}, 200)
```

Curiously enough, everything works fine on Chrome Canary [and all other major browsers].

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025510/scrolltop-not-working-in-chrome-safari) didn't help either.

Is it a known bug of current Chrome version [which is supposed to be fixed on Canary]? I will fallback to plain anchors + ids in case.

Comment: Not sure but you can try: `$('html, body').animation({'scrollTop': 300}, 200)`, it works on my Chrome browser (34.0.1847.116). I think in the other post, the problem is a load order problem, if the script is executed before the whole html page is rendered, you got problem with `$(...).offset().top`.

Comment: @Holt you got it man, thank you! Write is as an answer and I will mark as accepted ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$('html, body').animation({
    scrollTop: 300
}, 200);
```

It is what I use on my sites and it works well in Chrome (34.0.1847.116).

Considering the other post you pointed, the problems probably comes from the load order : The script is executed before all the post are rendered, so `$().offset().top` returns something incorrect.